# Wp_head and wp_footer vs wp_enqueue_script javascript files?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, headers, footer, wp-head

I'm converting a bootstrap html website into Wordpress.

Now, all recommend using wp_enqueue_script() for registering javascript files. i.e.

```
function themeslug_enqueue_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-js', 'filename.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeslug_enqueue_script' );
```

But I have some js files loading in the head and some other ones in the footer of the original html code.

I was going to use wp_head and wp_footer, is it ok to do so or better stick to wp_enqueue_script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've overlooked the *5th* input parameter of:

```
 wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer );
```

Namely the boolean `$in_footer` part, that will put the script in the *footer*, if set as `true`, else in the *header*.

You can also use `$deps` to handle dependencies.

Check out the [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) for more info.

=> I would stick to `wp_enqueue_script()` and not manually place the scripts into the header or footer.

Comment: Ah ok I didn't know that parameter existed. Well, then it's obvious that wp enqueue is the proper way to go. Thanks